# How to use Aadhar card api in our android application

Tags: android

I have tried below given code to integrate Aadhar card api in android  but i am unable to find any solution. Please suggest me.

I have use this code.
https://authportal.uidai.gov.in/developer

Comment: Try to share source code which you have tried not the official links here.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK is available for Aadhaar. You have to register on [Aadhaar Bridge website](http://bridge.aadhaarconnect.com/api-doc.html#/page/Android-SDK) and then you can get SDK.

If you want to scan QR code on Aadhaar card, check out these Android code [here](https://github.com/Zephrys/Auter) and [here](https://github.com/dimagi/AadharUID) on github.

Comment: The Aadhaar bridge website link is not working anymore. Can you please share some other ways to do this?

Comment: You can use Aadhar integration guidelines available now. Refer https://aadhaarapi.com/android-sdk-integration/